# tuple unpacking in X_test

Tags: python, pytorch

i am following a simple tutorial in PyTorch. The tutorial is using the diabetes dataset and built a simple two-layer network. In some part of the tutorial there exist the following part of the code where there exists an iteration on the X_test using enumerate.

```
predictions=[]
with torch.no_grad(): 
    
    for i, data in enumerate(X_test): 
        y_pred=model(data)
        
        predictions.append(y_pred.argmax().item()) 
       
        print(y_pred.argmax().item())
```

while I thought that I was understanding enumerate I am a little confused. What the i and data referring to in the above code?

in general, I understandnd that is a typle unpacking procedure

Comment: `enumerate()` creates an iterator which returns (index, value) tuples. The tuple unpacking is doing exactly that, unpacking the tuple returned by the `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` simply enumerates iterable items.

e.g.

```
my_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant']
print(list(enumerate(my_list)))
>> [(0, 'cat'), (1, 'dog'), (2, 'elephant')]
```

In your case `i` is an index of `data` variable in some loop state (it is not used tho) and `data` is a feature tensor of one row in your dataset.

Comment: when I am running the code of my question I get back a series of 010101... meaning that the patient have diabetes or not. While i is supposed to print the index why finally does not doing it?

Answer (score 0):

In enumerate, data of X_test is used to predict by the model, i is the index and data is the data which you are using to predict.
torch.argmax is the prediction which is stored in the predictions list
[more](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/making-prediction-with-argmax/49526)